# How to force tracker to re-index a folder?

Tags: indexing, tracker

I'm using the [tracker indexing tool](http://www.tracker-project.org) to search for and in files on my Ubuntu 10.10 amd64 system. Having recently added some of files into a single folder I wondered how to force tracker to re-index this folder so I would be able to perform search-queries on these files.

Any ideas? A terminal command would be completely sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This command will make Tracker reindex all its folders:

```
tracker-processes -r
```

Not exactly what you want, but has helped me quite a few times.

Answer (score 4):

With recent releases of `tracker` (mine is 1.12.0), you can force the re-indexing of a given folder simply typing:

```
tracker reset -f DIR_NAME
```

This causes the indexed information for `DIR_NAME` to be deleted and indexed again. Ir could be a directory or a file.

Comment: Tried it, now tracker just fails to start, from the journal: `Failed to start Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.`. I guess it will be fine after a reboot...

Answer (score 3):

tracker should watch the directory and automatically index any added files - so make sure watching is enabled in the preferences. but generally, my experience with tracker has been that it works inconsistently at best.

Comment: I know, that tracker has this auto-index feature, but there are situations, when you know, that some files have seen changes or were added and you know, that you'll use them a lot in the next few hours - so it would be good to have them at your fingertips instantly by manually forcing tracker to index these files/folders.

Comment: it's a shame people want manual access to force tracker to do something that it should be doing, but isn't.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if @methadata's answer should be correct, but for me, tracker was still not indexing the directory; I also tried `tracker index -f DIR_NAME`. The only thing that worked for me was to get tracker to completely wipe the index and start indexing again from scratch:

```
tracker reset -r     # shut down indexing and erase index
tracker daemon -s    # start indexing again
```

Source: [tracker docs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker/Documentation/First5Minutes)